# PHP output to CSV

Tags: php, csv

I have the following PHP script which reads from two CSV files, At the moment I am putting the data into a table however I need it to output to a CSV file...

```
<?php

$products_file = fopen('Products.csv', 'r');
$manufacturers_file = fopen('Manufacturers.csv', 'r');

$manufacturers = array();

while (($manufacturers_line = fgetcsv($manufacturers_file)) !== FALSE) {

     $manufacturers[$manufacturers_line[0]] = $manufacturers_line [1];

    }

echo '<table><tr><th>SKU</th><th>Make and Model</th><th>Make and Model</th></tr>';

while (($products_line = fgetcsv($products_file)) !== FALSE ) {

  echo '<tr><td>'.$products_line[3].'</td><td>';

  echo $manufacturers[$products_line[5]];

  echo '</td><td>'.$products_line[4].'</td></tr>';
}

echo '</table>';

fclose($products_file);
fclose($manufacturers_file);

?>
```

How can I do this using fputcsv ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php is all you need. The function takes a file handle and an array witch is saved in you're file on one line .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest this:

```
$outfile = fopen('output.csv', 'w');

while (($products_line = fgetcsv($products_file)) !== FALSE 
      && fputcsv(
        array($products_line[3], $manufacturers[$products_line[5]], $products_line[4]
      ) !== FALSE) {
  echo '<tr><td>'.$products_line[3].'</td><td>';
  echo $manufacturers[$products_line[5]];
  echo '</td><td>'.$products_line[4].'</td></tr>';
}
```

First, a new array is being created with
`array($products_line[3], $manufacturers[$products_line[5]], $products_line[4]`.
Then this array is being fed to `fputcsv()`.

The above code outputs both csv and html. Remove the `echo` if you don't want html output.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you just need to change where it renders the html table to write it to a csv file like this as from the PHP documentation:-

```
$fp = fopen('newfile.csv', 'w');

while (($products_line = fgetcsv($products_file)) !== FALSE )
{
  fputcsv($fp, $products_line);
}

fclose($fp);
```

Hope that helps.

Rick.

Comment: Mind though that this will output different values than what's in your html table.

Comment: This is true as it will just output the whole row but that depends what data he wants to print out. It can easily be changed like you did by creating a new array.

Comment: Ta very Richard, I did end upp using this in the end... nice one!

Comment: Ah your most welcome, shame I didn't get the answer though :)

Answer (score 3):

You could also do it this way:

Declare $csv outside your while loop:

```
$csv = '';
```

Then in your while loop populate the variable:

```
$csv .= $products_line[3].','.$manufacturers[$products_line[5]].','.$products_line[4]."\n";
```

Then once outside your loop you can write $csv to a file:

```
$myFile = 'testFile.csv';
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die('cannot open file');
fwrite($fh, $csv);
fclose($fh);
```

Done!

**Note** the double quote around the \n. If you use single quotes the \n character will not have the expected result.

Comment: +1 for double quote around the \n - I wouldn't have thought of that!